# C programming memset arpa.inet

Tags: c, memory, ip, memset

Hey sorry I am a newbie on C but the code down there I found it from tutorials point and I was just wondering if there is a specific reason why they used `\0`in memset function? or is it just random??

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

(...)

   int retval;
   struct in_addr addrptr

   memset(&addrptr, '\0', sizeof(addrptr));
   retval = inet_aton("68.178.157.132", &addrptr);
```

Comment: Usually using the null character sets the value of the memory to be null `\0` so that if you access the memory before setting it you don't get unexpected values from previous uses of the memory.

Comment: so \0 means null right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Hey, there! In case you confused this site with the tutorials point support forum: we are not.

Comment: @D.R.: `\0` is nothing. You mean `'\0'`, which is an `int` and the same as `0`. To add: this is only true for integer arrays. For all other (float's, pointers, etc.), it has little to no use if you are after portable code.

Comment: Oh, and: it's bad coding style for two reasons: 1) `'\0'` is a character. It obfuscates the code 2) it is not portable. Use an initialiser with a `0`. Will do the same, but portably for e.g. pointers.

Answer (score 0):

`'\0'` is the NUL (that's NUL not NULL) character (value = 0) which is a sensible default value to set memory to.

Note that terminology NULL is typically reserved for pointers.

Comment: is there a function where I can put '\0' null to whole memory? a function that I can access to whole memory

Comment: @user7387002 What do you mean "whole memory" ? `memset` sets a chunk of a specified size - if you need something different then it sounds like you are "doing it wrong".

Answer (score -1):

The null character `\0` will set the memory in question to a null value. This is useful because memory is not always "erased" when it is freed so it could still have a value from whatever was using that chunk of memory previously. By initializing to null, you guarantee you won't get unexpected values.

Comment: is there a function where I can put '\0' null to whole memory? a function that I can access to whole memory

Comment: Zeroing all bits does not guarantee null pointers or `0.=´ floats. Thus it is bad style at best, flawed actually.